# How to have usefull debugging or error messages from laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm a bit new to laravel, but I'm experienced in Php.
In previous works, I set a mecanism that allowed me to be informed when nearly any problem occurred on the server:

- I got full stack
- precise PHP error messages
- for nearly all king of errors
- a mail sent to me

So when I began to work with laravel, I tried to do the same things, and achieved:

- full stack
- a mail sent to me

But I can't have meaningful error in all case. One example:

```
$store = Store::create(...)
```

In this line I forget to specify the namespace (\App\Store::create), and I get those error messages:
first:

```
FatalThrowableError ; Type error: Argument 1 passed to App\Http\Controllers\User::create() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, array given, called in /var/www/html/laravel/blog/app/Http/Controllers/User.php on line 94
```

second:

```
ErrorException ; Trying to get property of non-object in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 156)
```

third:

```
FatalThrowableError ; Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::addCookieToResponse() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response, array given, called in /var/www/html/laravel/blog/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Session/Middleware/StartSession.php on line 72
```

I understand that laravel is a complex framework but I can't figure why it produces this errors, and how I can have more useful errors (as as it is I can only know that "something is bad").

Has someone an idea ?

¹ There is some errors that Php prefers to keep to himself (in its logs) :-)

Comment: The missing namespace example you mention will just throw a `Class not found` error.  Maybe you see those other errors as well, but they point to one or more separate, unrelated issues.  Sometimes the 2nd and 3rd errors in the trace are not very meaningful, as they're just cascading problems caused by the 1st.  But the 1st is accurate and useful, eg here it tells you very accurately what the problem is ... (and it is easy then to imagine that with a messed up `$request`, the CSRF token is messed up, as is the cookie, explaining the following 2 errors).

Comment: I already have taken into account the CSRF token, so it should not cause this problem. Thanks for your comment and please the answer.

Comment: Checkout WInston, would help you timesfold.

Comment: I don't understand what you said. I am not an english native speaker and do not understand "timesfold", and I didn't find any project called  WInston (well, to be more precise I didn't found one that seems to answer my problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally cornered the problem and I learned a lot.
I thank for their benevolence @Don't Panic and @Vitalmax !

The error was that I forgot that PHP namespaces are case insensitive: in my post I cleaned a bit the code as I knew that it didn't stick to the code's conventions (a controller's name must begin with a capital letter). Originally my controller name was **user** and the faulty code was:

```
$user = User::create(...)
```

As you can guess PHP believed that I wanted to call **user::create** (as I have such a method in my controller) and not **User::create** (as I wanted).

What I learned:

- don't alter the code when asking for help
- Laravel use a cache system that can get in the way of the debugging (see a question that I asked on [laracast's forum](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/a-precise-string-in-a-blade-make-laravel-rendering-of-a-page-failing) )
- take more time to read the error message; I know this rule but I keep doing otherwise

Answer (score 0):

> When you start a new Laravel project, error and exception handling is
>   already configured for you. The App\Exceptions\Handler class is where
>   all exceptions triggered by your application are logged and then
>   rendered back to the user.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/errors

I recommend you to dive into the official docs and into your `App\Exceptions\Handler`.

Maybe you are looking for `report` and `render` methods in that class.

Comment: Sorry but as I said I already made possible the sending of email when an exception occurred, so I already know and used the Handler.  
The problem is the quality of the exception: there is only laravel's internal exceptions generated but not the "real one" as I showed in my example. Those exception are clearly useless.

Comment: @lemmel Why do you think those exceptions are useless? Laravel is a framework and it knows nothing about your business logic. You are free to create your own exceptions that make sense. You can catch laravel's built in exceptions and your own in that `Handler`, do some stuff (email, log) behind the scenes and show your user some error page.

Comment: I probably wasn't clear enough: I already use the logs mecanism (e.g. I have customized the Handler class). The problem is that when there is an error with a missing namespace, laravel throws exceptions that doesn't help (please read again my original question).

Comment: @lemmel I tried Laravel from a fresh install and when I forget to specify a namespace it gives me `(1/1) FatalThrowableError Class 'Store' not found` (along with the whole stack trace). I think this error makes sense. Did i get your question right? If so, please provide more `User` controller code please.

Comment: You did get it; and I agree your exception is useful. I think there is something fishy in my code/installation/setup: I got a strange behaviour that I reported on laracast: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/a-precise-string-in-a-blade-make-laravel-rendering-of-a-page-failing   
   For the time I will go to bed (I'm on GMT +2, and not so young and 
 combative :-) ), I will come back tomorrow in the afternoon. Thanks !

Comment: @lemmel There is a lack of stack traces. Please provide your UserController and Exception handler classes.